# Automatically extract useful cars from car site

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am using puppeteer to extract data and see when a car that meets my requirements shows up, this is what I did so far. I would like some basic syntax advice, or more advanced tips as well.

I tried to follow this best practices:

- Give meaningful names to variables
- Only explain what seems not obvious
- Split code into functions to make it more readable.

Currently the code takes a while, I am not sure how to speed it up just yet.

**Code**

```javascript
import puppeteer, {type Page, type Browser} from "puppeteer";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const baseURL = "https://www.arnoldclark.com/used-cars";
  //based off conditions that I want, done manually in the website
  const city = "cityName"
  const search =
    "?payment_type=cash&min_price=4000&max_price=8000&location=${city}%2C UK&photos_only=true&unreserved_only=true&roadtax_cost=30&mileage=72000&age=6&seats[]=4&seats[]=5&show_click_and_collect_options=true&sort_order=mileage";

  await page.goto(baseURL + search);

  // car URL from link
  const carUrls = await page.$$eval("h2.ac-vehicle__title a", (carLinks) =>
    carLinks.map((link) => link.href)
  );

  const candidates = await getCandidates(browser, carUrls);

  console.table(candidates);

  await browser.close();
})();

interface Car { 
  favs: number;
  url: string;
}

async function getCandidates(browser: Browser, carUrls: string[]) {
  const candidates:Car[] = [];
  await Promise.all(
    carUrls.map(async (url) => {
      const newPage = await browser.newPage();
      await newPage.goto(url);
      try {
        // may be loaded dynamically
        const favs = await newPage.$eval(
          ".ac-productheader__content-wrapper span",
          (el) => el.textContent
        );
        if(favs) candidates.push({ favs: Number.parseInt(favs.split(" ")[0]), url });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("no favs");
      }
      newPage.close()
    })
  );
  return candidates.sort((a, b) => b.favs - a.favs).slice(0, 4);
}
```

**Sample output**

```
┌─────────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ (index) │ favs │                                                url                                                │
├─────────┼──────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│    0    │  87  │       'https://www.arnoldclark.com/used-cars/kia/picanto/1-0-1-5dr/2018/ref/arnai-u-92166'        │
│    1    │  31  │     'https://www.arnoldclark.com/used-cars/suzuki/celerio/1-0-sz3-5dr/2018/ref/arnai-u-92266'     │
│    2    │  31  │       'https://www.arnoldclark.com/used-cars/ford/ka/1-2-studio-5dr/2017/ref/arnaj-u-41340'       │
│    3    │  29  │ 'https://www.arnoldclark.com/used-cars/dacia/sandero/1-2-16v-ambiance-5dr/2017/ref/arndv-u-75527' │
└─────────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Did you checked times to run parts? Like if the request was long, if it's because of sorting etc?

Comment: wdym ? I think it just takes time because it is http-ing to each URL @Elikill58

Comment: Yes but how much? Does one URL is more longer than others? Are they representing 90% of total time or 10% of it? It can be a good start to know where time is used

Comment: Using `({headless:false})` 99% of the time is occupied by the process sending 20 http requests for pages (and each page requests extra assets) at once and waiting the content to arrive. @Elikill58